Salesforce - Email template Opportunity Merge fields not showing in real time but works in 'Send test and Verify Merge Fields'
I have created a flow in Salesforce which sends an email when a field in the Opportunity object is updated. The email template is as below. This email template was created in classic and is of form text.
Dear {!Contact.AgentName__c},
Your deal {!Oppotunity.Name} was funded on {!Opportunity.CloseDate}.
Regards,
{!Organization.Name}
When I try to 'Send test and Verify Merge Fields' it works fine, i.e. all the merge fields populate. But when I activate a flow and actually change the required field to trigger the flow. This is how I receive the email.
Dear John,
Your deal  was funded on  .
Regards,
ABC Corp
I am not sure why the Opportunity merge fields do not populate.
I have tried using the merge fields from Account as a test, i.e. I used {!Account.Name} and it populates that. It's just the Opportunity field that does not populate.

what did you specify as the flow email action's target record id? oppty id or something else? Field security permissions? Even if you're admin you should have the Read checkboxes ticked. The {!Oppotunity.Name} is just here in stackoverflow or in source too?

I created a Get record element before the email action, which gets the contact ID associated with the triggered Opportunity. I used that ID to specify in the Recipient ID, I did not specify anything in Related Record ID. The 'Name' field does exist in Opportunity object. Can you please let me know how I can check if I have the Read checkboxes checked in Field Security permissions? I did not verify that yet.

Put oppty id in "related record id", "target id" or whatever is the flow name for that; contact's id is not enough. When you "send test and verify merge fields" it asks you for contact and oppty, doesn't it.
Permissions - will be in your Profile or Permission Sets assigned to you. Object settings -> Opportunity -> check if you have at least Read checkboxes

I added the opp id in related record id and it worked. Thank you so much.
